# Getting Chrome Storage Value from Function (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

First Post, so forgive me for any general practices that I haven't followed.

Also very new to Chrome extension and Javascript so apologies for my noob question

I have the following code but getting the console is say undefined

```
    function getFromStorage(key) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (r) {
        const returnVal = r[key]
        console.log(returnVal)
        return returnVal
    })
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((selectionText) => {
    var Val = getFromStorage("value")
    console.log(Val)
});
```

But when I run the chrome.storage.sync.get in the listener, it works fine.
I have a few values from storage that I want to grab so thought a function would be better.

btw, using Manifest V3

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your getFromStorage doesn't return anything. It just calls an asynchronous API, then the callback runs and returns a value into the internals of the `chrome` API, which simply ignores this value.

Since `chrome.storage` returns a Promise in modern Chrome you can just `await` it directly.
Note that the function should be declared as `async` to allow using `await` inside.

```js
async function getFromStorage(key) {
  return (await chrome.storage.sync.get(key))[key];
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async info => {
  let Val = await getFromStorage('value');
  console.log(Val);
});
```

Comment: Done this and now got another error.
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Full Code

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'test',
        title: 'test',
        contexts: ['all']
    });
});
async function getFromStorage(key) {
    return (await chrome.storage.sync.get(key))[key];
}
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    let Val = await getFromStorage('daysValue');
    console.log(Val);
});

Running as a Service Worker in Manifest V3

Comment: Please read the note about `async` in the answer and add it to your listener as shown in the answer.